# How do I get 2 desks in PewDiePie tuber simulators

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

[image]

Does any one know how to duplicate the desks in PewDiePie tuber simulator

Answer (score 1):

The second desk (the one to the left) was part of a special celebratory BUX-package that was available for a limited time when the game celebrated it's one year anniversary in late September 2017.

Link to a [video showing someone buying the pack](https://youtu.be/PKp2re2t_ig?t=38s).